# delete the clicked cell on collection view

Tags: ios

when I run my code there are a few cell on my collection view, now I try click on which one and delete the clicked cell but every time the firs one cell on my array is deleted !!!
here is my cod:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // 1 = Tapped yes
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // ....

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [MainCollectionView indexPathForCell:MainCollectionView];
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [MainCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         [cellImages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [MainCollectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on my indexPath, would somebody tell me what is wrong??

Comment: `[MainCollectionView indexPathForCell:MainCollectionView]` Meaning?

Comment: I tried by this code choose the clicked cell on my uicollectionview (maincollectionview)...

Comment: The method is called `indexPathForCell` and expect a cell at the end, and you're giving a UICollectionView. That's why the IndexPath return a 0,0.
Use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a variable to store the indexPath of the clicked view ?

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _clickedIndexPath = indexPath;
    //Show AlertView
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [cellImages removeObjectAtIndex:_clickedIndexPath.row];
        [_collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[_clickedIndexPath]];
    }
}
```

Either that or store the clickedCell, to use : `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_yourCollectionView indexPathForCell:_theClickedCell];`